# Redirect loop in PhP

Tags: php, loops, redirect

This is the part that redirects in the "login.php" file.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    if($_SESSION != ''){
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
}
```

This redirects from "home.php" file.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
if($_SESSION['user'] == ''){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

How does this loop?

Comment: What exactly your code problem is?

Comment: In login.php move 2nd condition above first , this will chk if session is present or not.add` !empty` to this first condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($_SESSION != '')
```

This is **always** true. So, your `$_SESSION['user']` is an empty string and from `home.php` you will redirect to `login.php`. Here `$_SESSION['user']` is set, so you will redirect to `home.php` as well.